# Find value with iat with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I put elif inside this line 4?

I have this code:

```
A1 = df.iat[1,11]
A2 = df.iat[1,10]
A3 = df.iat[1,9]
df['AColumn'] = A1 if A1==A1 elif A2==A2 else A3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with two Ternary Operators

```py
df['AColumn'] = A1 if A1==A1 else A2 if A2==A2 else A3
```

Comment: `A1==A1` is False if `A1 is None`

Answer (score 1):

Only way `A1` won’t be equal to itself is if it is `nan`. This will grab the first non null value.

```
df[‘AColumn’] = max([A1, A2, A3], key=pd.notna)
```